# Singleton pattern for derivable class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

In the normal singleton pattern, the singleton class is effectively "sealed" (cannot be derived):

```
class A
{
private:
    static A m_instance; // instance of this class, not a subclass

    // private ctor/dtor, so class can't be derived
    A();
    ~A();

public:
    static A& GetInstance() { return m_instance; }

    ...
};
```

How would you write a class that is meant to be derived, but whose derived class should only be instantiated once?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739678/c-templates-and-the-singleton-pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would you write a class that is meant to be derived, but whose derived class should only be instantiated once?

You can use the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to realize that:

```
template<typename Derived>
class A
{
protected: // Allow to call the constructor and destructor from a derived class
    A(); 
    ~A();

public:
    static T& GetInstance() { 
        static T theInstance; // Better way than using a static member variable
        return theInstance;
    }

    ...
};
```

And use that like

```
class B : public A<B> {
    // Specific stuff for derived class
};
```

---

Note that this way makes most sense, if the base class provides some common implementation (besides the `GetInstance()` function) realized, based on an interface provided by the derived class.

Whenever a call to the derived class in the base class is needed you can safely use a `static_cast<Derived*>(this)` to access it (no `virtual` or pure `virtual` functions needed):

```
 template<typename Derived> 
 void A<Derived>::doSomething {
      // Execute the functions from Derived that actually implement the 
      // warranted behavior.
      static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo();
      static_cast<Derived*>(this)->bar();
 }
```

Comment: Is `static T theInstance;` objectively "better"? Surely both compile to the same thing?

Comment: @Michael it won't compile to the same thing, and that's why it's better.

Comment: @Michael Lookup the _Scott Meyer's Singleton_ and why that's the advanced and better way (e.g. thread safety).