# Invalid initialization of type using class templates

Tags: c++, templates, singleton

I have a rather complicate singleton template starting with

```
template <class T>
class Singleton {
 public:
    static T& GetInstance(){
    static T instance;
    return instance;
}
 private:
    Singleton() {}
    ~Singleton() = default; 
};
```

and then

```
class Class2;

template <class T>
class Class1{
  void sayHi();
};

using Class1Singleton= Singleton<Class1<Class2>>;
```

So you can see I have a singleton of Class1 (that is also template based so I use Class2 for that).

Then in another part of the code I have

```
Class1Singleton & anObject= Class1Singleton::GetInstance();
```

When I try to build this I get this error

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 
‘Class1Singleton& {aka Singleton<Class1<Class2> >&}’ 
from expression of type ‘Class1<Class2>’
         Class1Singleton::GetInstance();
                                       ^
```

Why is the Singleton being ignored??

Comment: I think you want `Class1<Class2>& anObject= Class1Singleton::GetInstance();`.

Comment: `Singleton<Class1<Class2>>` returns a reference to `Class1<Class2>`. Why do you think you should be able to initialize a reference of type `Singleton<Class1<Class2>>&` by an object of type `Class1<Class2>`?

Comment: @DanielLangr What? Could you elaborate please? How can I return the singleton?

Comment: @songyuanyao in that case, would `anObject` be a singleton?

Comment: @KansaiRobot Your `Singleton<T>::GetInstance()` returns a reference to an object of type `T`, not of type `Singleton<T>`. In you case, `T` is `Class1<Class2>`. This: `Class1Singleton & anObject = Class1Singleton::GetInstance();` translates to `Singleton<Class1<Class2>> & anObject = ` _a reference to an object of type `Class1<Class2>`.

Comment: @DanielLangr I see. I have two questions: 1) Is the return object reference a singleton?  2) If not, how can I return a singleton?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/580083 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/271104/580083. Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5739678/580083.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
template <class T>
class Singleton {
public:
    static T& GetInstance();
};
Singleton<T>& anObject = Singleton<T>::GetInstance();
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type is T&
//^^^^^^^^^^^ type is Singleton<T>&
```

The types don't match up. You are trying to initialize a reference to `Singleton<T>` with a reference to `T`.

You ask in the comments, "how can I return a singleton?". If you really want to return a `Singleton<T>` you can:

```
template <class T>
class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton<T>& GetInstance() {
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ return the type you want to return
        static Singleton<T> instance;
        return instance;
    }
 private:
    Singleton() = default;
    ~Singleton() = default; 
};
```

Comment: Thanks!. One more question: If I get the singleton in a variable say `anObject', is there a way to access the methods of `Class1` from there? like how to call `sayHi()` from the singleton?

Comment: The `Singleton<T>` you've got so far doesn't have a `T` in it. If `Singleton<T>` contained a `T` and you had an accessor to a reference to that `T`, you could call methods. Alternatively, keep `GetInstance` returning a `T&` which is more useful, but didn't seem to be what you wanted to do.