# Undefined reference when calling a singleton

Tags: c++, templates, singleton, linker-errors

This is a follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65070832/invalid-initialization-of-type-using-class-templates/65078070#65078070)  (I will post the necessary class definitions at the end so that to understand it)

This time I have

```
Class1<Class2> & anObject= Class1Singleton::GetInstance();
```

I corrected the previous error, so that now `GetInstance()` that returns an object of type `Class1` (not a singleton!) is assigned to the correct type.

I try to build this and it compiles!
However this time I got a linker error

```
undefined reference to Singleton<Class1<Class2>>::GetInstance()
collerc2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

At first I thought it was not a singleton anymore, but actually `Class1Singleton` is a singleton!
Why is the linker not able to reference its function?

---

The classes are:

```
template <class T>
class Singleton {
public:
    static T& GetInstance()
    {
        static T instance;
        return instance;
    }

private:
    Singleton() {}
    ~Singleton() = default;
}
```

and

```
class Class2;

template <class T>
class Class1{
  void sayHi();
};

using Class1Singleton= Singleton<Class1<Class2>>;
```

Comment: WOW! really??? Thanks I ll read it and try and report the results

Comment: The indentation got me confused. I fixed it. Now I am unsure of the error.

Comment: You deleted the link? I was going to read it

Comment: I am doubtful that this applies now: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: WOW. It seems to work! I am now in a meeting at work so cannot check throughfully but it seems it is compiling and linking ok.. Will report later

Comment: @JaMiT corrected . Thanks